How to properly scale Dash Bootstrap page?
I have a page that looks good when the scale is 90%:

But if I change it to 100% scale it starts to look like this:

I tried to add some col-lg-* and col-12 to my Cols classnames attributes, but that just causes them to overlap. What I need is equally scaling of each element, without any of them causing another to change "row".
Here's the app.py script:
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, dcc

dash_bootstrap_components
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG])
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True              
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='csv-store'),                        
    dcc.Store(id='json-store'),                         
    html.Div(error_message, className='error-message'),  

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([button_download], width=6, className='text-start'),    
                dbc.Col([pdf_button], width=6, className='text-start')          
            ], className='align-center mb-3 g-0')
        ], width=3),

        dbc.Col([dbc.Row([
            html.H1('Patient data', className='fs-4 text-center'),              
            survey_table],                                                      
            style={'backgroundColor': '#201F21'}, className='pb-5')],
            width=9, className='mt-3 pe-4 ps-4')
    ]),

    html.Div(style={'height': '30px'}),                                         

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([

            dbc.Row([

                dbc.Col([
                    dbc.Row([dbc.CardBody([html.H2('Table Data', className='fs-2 text-center')],
                                          style={'backgroundColor': '#201F21'}, className='pe-2 mb-3')]),  
                    dbc.Row([dbc.CardBody(
                        [
                            biomarkers_table                                                               
                        ], style={'backgroundColor': '#201F21'},
                        className='col-4 col-md-4, col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-xxl-2 p-2 mt-3'
                    )]),
                ]),

                dbc.Col([linear_chart], className='col-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-xxl-5'),           

                dbc.Col([linear_chart2], className='col-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-xxl-5')]),       

            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([dbc.CardBody([spirometry_table], style={'backgroundColor': '#201F21'}, className='mt-3 p-2')],
                        width=2),                                                   


                dbc.Col([linear_chart3], width=5),                                  


                dbc.Col([linear_chart4], width=5)]),                                

        ], width=12),
    ]),

    dbc.Row([html.Img(src="./assets/images/Halitus.png", height=50,
                      style={'width': '200px'})])                                   
], className='m-0 px-3')

callback_pool(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)


maybe you should put both plots in one row and it put in column. or maybe you should add percentage width directly to plots. It may need to run code and change classes directly in web browser using DevTools. But this would need  (even fake)  plots and other element to run it.
